# Visual Studio Code - ложные ошибки на правильный синтаксис mySQL

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code

Почему на строку:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD `date_practic` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL AFTER `date_exam`;
```

**Visual Studio Code** ывдаёт ошибку синтаксиса: Incorrect syntax near <kbd>`</kbd>.
Почему он считает, что знак "backquote" (его здесь просто невозможно написаьт второй раз, даже через тег kbd), является синтаксической ошибкой? Ведь это как раз и есть синтаксис MySQL.
Или Visual Studio плохой редактор для mySQL-кода?

Comment: *Или Visual Studio плохой редактор для mySQL-кода?* Да вообще никакой... откуда фирме Майкрософт узнать про существование SQL-синтаксиса, отличного от синтаксиса SQL Server?

Comment: Думаете что плагины пишут только в MS?

Comment: Могу предположить, что вы установили плагин `SQL Server (mssql)`, который заточен именно под ms sql (что следует из его названия). Попробуйте этот плагин удалить и поставить например SQLTools или SQL Language Server.

Comment: @Akina, был как-то небольшой опыт работы с MS SQL, глубоко не ковырял, но разницу в синтаксисе особой не заметил, может мелочи, которые даже в памяти не отложились.

Comment: @insolor, Верно говорите, он как-то выскачил автоматом, я его поставил автоматом и не заметил. что он именно что "SQL Server (mssql)"!
Спасибо за ответ!
P.S. Внимательность с годами проходит быстро.

Answer (score 1):

а у вас установлен соответствующий плагин для mysql?

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cweijan.vscode-mysql-client2

https://www.sqlshack.com/visual-studio-code-for-mysql-and-mariadb-development/

Comment: Странно, удалил тот плагин, установил кучу по названию mySQL, но проблема, т.е. не проблема, а поведение VSC на знак "backquote" осталось прежним.
Вероятно как работал в DW, так лучше и буду в нём работать - лучше редактора кода, пока значит не нашёл.